# Errors with Vagrant and Ubuntu 12.10 with RVM

Tags: 12.10, rvm, vagrant

Installed Vagrant via `sudo apt-get install vagrant`, and every time I try to run some vagrant command, such as `vagrant init precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box` I get the following error:

```
/home/novito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- log4r (LoadError)
    from /home/novito/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:2:in `<main>'
```

Not sure why rvm gets involved here, but oh well, I hope you guys can guide me on how to solve this.

Answer (score 7):

When you installed Vagrant using `apt-get` it would have installed all its required dependencies for the standard Ubuntu-packaged version of Ruby. But your error message indicates that when you run `vagrant` it is trying to use a version of Ruby (and its Gems) that is managed by RVM rather than the system version, and your version of Ruby is missing at least one of its dependencies, `log4r`.

I think you have a few options:

1. Revert to using the system (standard Ubuntu) version of Ruby by running something like `rvm use system --default` to reset RVM by default, and only change Ruby versions when you need to.
2. Switch back to the system version just when running Vagrant, so run `rvm use system` before running `vagrant` in the same shell.
3. Identify all the Ruby Gems that Vagrant depends on and manually install them in your RVM-managed Ruby installation. This would be a fiddly approach, though. It used to be possible to install Vagrant itself as a Ruby Gem, so you could have installed it in your RVM-managed Ruby installation, but that is not supported any more.

See the [RVM command options](https://rvm.io/rvm/cli) documentation for more detail on controlling which version of Ruby you are using.

Comment: I still get this error, even when using the default Ubuntu ruby version.

Answer (score 3):

After I downloaded and installed Vagrant from the [download page](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) the error goes away.

Comment: Started following (http://swaeku.github.io/blog/2013/03/09/installing-vagrant-on-ubuntu-12-dot-10/) these steps and got the error. The binary from vagrant site is working without an issue. To install run "dpkg -i name_of_package.deb"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  As it turns out, apparently you need ruby 1.9.3.  I had installed Vagrant from source with 2.0.0 and the aforementioned error occurred until I reinstalled the gem with ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had a old custom ruby environment installed in my home (`~/.rbenv`) and this apparently overrides all the default system Ruby packages. When I deleted that folder, Vagrant started working just fine.